# Jquery object innerHTML working in Firefox but not IE?

Tags: jquery, xml-parsing, innerhtml

In summary I have a xml string which I use jQuery to find some children of a specific node.

These children and their values are used to build a HTML select box and append it to a webpage.

**The XML**

```
<!--- Another node level !-->          
       <Salutation restricted="no" type="dropdownBox" tooltip="Select a title for the customer" required="yes" size="6">
           <value>Mr</value>
           <value>Sir</value>
           <value>Mrs</value>
           <value>Miss</value>
           <value>Lord</value>
       </Salutation>
```

**The Code**

```
    function dropdownBuilder( xml, element, id ) {
       // find node with specific name and get its children
       selection = $("<div>" + xml + "</div>").find(element).children();
       console.log( selection );
       // generate a select box
       var selectBox = "<select id=\"" + id + "\"> ";
       for ( var j = 0; j < selection.length; j++ ) {
        selectBox += "<option value=\"" + selection[j].innerHTML + "\">"
                + selection[j].innerHTML + "</option>";
       }
       selectBox += "</select>";

       // return html
       return selectBox;
}
```

**Output FIREFOX**

```
<select id="dropdownBox1" data-hasqtip="true" aria-describedby="qtip-1">
    <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
    <option value="Sir">Sir</option>
    <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
    <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
    <option value="Lord">Lord</option>
</select>
```

**Output IE**

```
<select id="dropdownBox1" data-hasqtip="true" jQuery16309410884371447445="60"/>
```

In the console log in IE it just says **"LOG: [object Object] "**

I have tried changing to output using .val() , .value , .data , .attr

Any idea why this works fine in FF but not in IE?

**JSFIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/BA7u6/1/

Thanks

Comment: try `selection.eq(j).html()` ?

Comment: nope still the same problem on IE, it worked ok on Firefox

Comment: Then `selection` is empty, and something is wrong with `$("<div>" + xml + "</div>").find(element).children()`, probably the xml that's passed as a string to jQuery.

Comment: I just did console.log(xml) and it prints out a valid string of my xml

Comment: can you create this is a jsfiddle?

Comment: sure here you go http://jsfiddle.net/BA7u6/1/

Comment: this works fine for me in ie9 and 10: http://jsfiddle.net/BA7u6/2/

Comment: The fiddle is working for me in IE9 both as you've provided and with my answer below...  http://jsfiddle.net/shaneblake/ZSuWc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the for loop in you code with this and it should work :

```
selection.each(function(index) {
    var text = $(this).text();
    selectBox += "<option value=\"" + text + "\">" + text + "</option>";
});
```

Comment: Your missing a closing ")" but it still does not work in IE, but firefox is Ok

Answer (score 1):

you should use an xml parser to do what you are after

see this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: Thanks but I already do this at an earlier stage in my getXML function, sorry I should have included that